# Which abstract nouns do we use indefinite articles with?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which abstract nouns do we use indefinite articles with? I always can't decide whether I have to add an article before non-specific abstract noun or not. Please, give me some instructions.

Comment: Can you give an example of one that puzzles you?

Comment: I mean, is there a special rule with them? Or do we just have to memorize the words that we don't use with?

Comment: Abstract nouns are usually [uncountable](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm) , and so do not take an article. That's all I can tell you without examples. See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84414/how-to-distinguish-countable-and-uncountable-senses